# Hibernate Custom ID Type with @GeneratedValue

Tags: hibernate, jpa

we work with DDD and we would like to have custom types for our entities instead of using Long or String primitifs.

I have followed some tutorials to create an EnhancedUserType that allows hibernate to recognize my type and convert it from / to String value.

The problem is when I try to use @Id and @GeneratedValue.

The basic @SequenceStyleGenerator does not seem to support that out of the box.

It fails during the Identity generation and more precisely in the bellow code, since it only manages numeric types:

*IdentityGeneratorHelper.hava*

```
public static IntegralDataTypeHolder getIntegralDataTypeHolder(Class<?> integralType) {
        if ( integralType == Long.class
                || integralType == Integer.class
                || integralType == Short.class ) {
            return new BasicHolder( integralType );
        }
        else if ( integralType == BigInteger.class ) {
            return new BigIntegerHolder();
        }
        else if ( integralType == BigDecimal.class ) {
            return new BigDecimalHolder();
        }
        else {
            throw new IdentifierGenerationException(
                    "Unknown integral data type for ids : " + integralType.getName()
            );
        }
```

Is it possible to extend the basic sequence generator but make it work for my custom type ?

Here is my relative code:

https://github.com/sashokbg/jpa_sandbox/blob/chore/generated_embedded_key/src/main/java/com/example/generated_embeded_key/Company.java

There is also an integration test using test containers, that you can run to play around:

https://github.com/sashokbg/jpa_sandbox/blob/chore/generated_embedded_key/src/test/java/com/example/generated_embeded_key/GeneratedEmbededKeyTest.java